# Create ePub from Markdown with Pandoc API

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I could create an EPUB e-book from the pandoc CLI like this:

```
pandoc -o book-cli.epub book.md
```

But I am rather interested in using the pandoc API, so I tried re-creating the same book like this:

```
import Text.Pandoc
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

main = readFile "book.md" >>= writeEPUB def . readMarkdown def >>= B.writeFile "book.epub"
```

While `book-cli.epub` is completely fine, `book.epub` contains only the headings and no contents. I tried on several EPUB readers and noticed the same behavior. Here is the full content of `book.md`:

```
This is my book!

# Chapter One

Chapter one is over.

# Chapter Two

Chapter two has just begun.
```

I am guessing that I have to supply some particular options instead of using `def`, but I couldn't figure out exactly what needs to be done from pandoc's API documentation.

Comment: The best place to ask is on the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) mailing list.